# Shared Service variable is undefined when checking for logged user

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I intend to check if a user is logged in, this information should be available throughout the application.

To do this I have used this code in a shared service file **user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  public loggedIn:boolean;

  constructor() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.loggedIn=true;
      } else {
        this.loggedIn=false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I then injected this service into a navbar component as so

**(navigation-bar.component.ts)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation-bar',
  templateUrl: './navigation-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavigationBarComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn$ = this.userService.isLoggedIn;

  constructor(private userService:UserService, private router:Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**(navigation-bar.component.html)**

```
<li class="nav-item px-2">
  <button type="button" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-info">{{ 
userService.loggedIn===undefined?'undefined':userService.loggedIn }} 
</button>
</li>
<li *ngIf="!userService.loggedIn" class="nav-item px-2">
  <button type="button" (click)="login()" class="btn btn- 
info">Login</button>
 </li>
<li *ngIf="userService.loggedIn" class="nav-item px-2">
  <button type="button" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-info">Log 
out</button>
</li>
```

The `userService.loggedIn` variable is `undefined`, I want it to show either true or false depending on whether the user is signed in or not.

Answer (score 4):

It is not defined until the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` observable is completed. You can set `loggedIn` as `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` and use `async` pipe to get the value. Like this:

```
export class UserService {

  private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public isLoggedIn = this.loggedIn.asObservable();


  constructor() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.loggedIn.next(true);
      } else {
        this.loggedIn.next(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the component `.ts`:

```
isLoggedIn$ = this.userService.isLoggedIn;
constructor(private userService:UserService) {}
```

In the `.html`:

```
<li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn$ | async" /* ... */>
  ...
</li>
```

Comment: I have the same issue, initially `isLoggedIn$ | async` is displaying false, but when I navigate to a different  component the correct value is displayed

Comment: Are you firing auth state change on navigation? If so, this might be why you get state change when navigating. Try to change the state manually to check if state change reflects well.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean by 'firing auth state change on navigation'

Comment: I mean, when is the callback function in `onAuthStateChanged()` is triggered?

Comment: I have added the complete .ts file. Please have a look. I have not added a callback function anywhere.

Comment: I think I get it. It displays `false` in the beginning because we give [BehaviorSubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)`false` in the beginning. When you navigate to a different component, I think `firebase` is looking for auth state again therefore it is fired and changes the value of `isLoggedIn`. I think you need to have a look at the Firebase docs at this point.